# How to add multiple sections[] and subfeilds[] inside fields[] in vue js html?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

How to add multiple `sections[]` and `subfields[]` inside `fields[]`?

My HTML form:

```
    <div class="col-md-12 mr-auto" id="regBox">
      <form class="form" method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="handelSubmit($event);">                    
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="material-icons">room</i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <select class="form-control" v-model="type" name="type" required="">
              <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Type here</option>
              <option value="option">option</option> 
              <option value="text">text</option> 
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rule Name" v-model="text" required="" maxlength="20">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content" v-for="(bok, index) in feilds" :key="index">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="material-icons">face</i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name..." v-model="bok.name" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="material-icons">face</i>
              </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Section..." v-model="bok.sections[0]" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">
              <i class="material-icons">face</i>
            </span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name..." v-model="bok.subfeilds[0].name" required="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <h3>The JSON value of <code>bok</code></h3>
      <textarea rows="3" cols="75%" readonly>{{ JSON.stringify(bok) }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <a @click="addNewRules">Add Another Rule</a>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-round">Get Started</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

VueJS code:

```
regBox = new Vue({
el: "#regBox",
  data: {
   type:'',
   text:'',
   feilds : [{
        name : null,
        sections:[null],
        subfeilds : [{name:null}],

    }],
  },

  methods: {
    addNewRules: function() {
    this.feilds.push({  name : null,
        sections:[null],
        subfeilds : [{name:null}],
         });
        },
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
           var vm = this;
           data = {};
           data['feilds'] = this.feilds;
           data['type'] = this.type;
           data['text'] = this.text;
            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://localhost:4000/add/act/',
              data: data,
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(e) {
                        if (e.status)
              {
                alert("Registration Success");


            }
              else {
                alert("Registration Failed");
                vm.response = e;

              }
          }
            });
            return false;
},
},
});
```

My problem arises when I add `fields[]`. `sections[]` should be an array so, how can I add multiple sections inside fields . Also how can I add multiple subfields inside the `fields[]`.

The code provided was perfectly working. The only issue is that I am not able to have multiple `sections[]` and `subfields[]`, which is required.

Comment: Can you give an example of data you would start with in `fields`, and how it would be different after the change you want to make?

Comment: Sir, the html is given..  in that how can I add multiple bok.sections and bok.subfeilds.name. now I am only able to add one bok.sections and one bok.subfeilds.name. I need multiple sections and multiple book.subfeilds.nams

Comment: Is your question, then, how to *display* multiple sections and subfields? You should use a `v-for` in each case.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form" method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="handelSubmit($event);"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="material-icons">room</i> </span> </div> <select class="form-control" v-model="type" name="type" > <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Type here</option> <option value="option">option</option> <option value="text">text</option> </select> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i> </span> </div> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rule Name" v-model="text" maxlength="20"> </div> </div> <div class="card-content" v-for="bok in feilds"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="material-icons">face</i> </span> </div> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username..." v-model="bok.name" > </div> </div> <div v-for="child in bok.subfeilds"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="material-icons">face</i> </span> </div> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Offences..." v-model="child.name" > </div> </div> </div> <a class="btn btn-success" @click="addChild(bok)">Add Offence</a> <div v-for="(secure,index) in bok.sections"> <div class="form-group"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text"> <i class="material-icons">face</i> </span> </div> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Section..." v-model="bok.sections[index]" > </div> </div> </div> <a class="btn btn-success" @click="addSection(bok)">Add</a> <h3>The JSON value of <code>bok</code></h3> <textarea rows="3" cols="75%" class="form-control" readonly>{{ JSON.stringify(bok) }}</textarea> </div> <a @click="addNewRules">Add Another Rule</a> <div class="text-center"> <button class="btn btn-primary btn-round">Get Started</button> </div> </form>

regBox = new Vue({
el: "#regBox",
  data: {
   type:'',
   text:'',
   feilds : [{
        name : null,
        sections:[],
        subfeilds : [{name:null}],      
    }],
  },

  methods: {
        addNewRules: function() {
        this.feilds.push({  name : null,
        sections:[],
        subfeilds : [{name:null}],
         });
        },
        addChild: function(bok) {
              bok.subfeilds.push({});
        },
        addSection: function(bok) {
              bok.sections.push({});
        },
     handelSubmit: function(e) {
           var vm = this;
           data = {};
           data['feilds'] = this.feilds;
           data['type'] = this.type;
           data['text'] = this.text;
            $.ajax({
              url: 'http://localhost:4000/add/act/',
              data: data,
              type: "POST",
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(e) {
                        if (e.status)
              {
                alert("Registration Success");


            }
              else {
                alert("Registration Failed");
                vm.response = e;

              }
          }
            });
            return false;
},
},
});
```

---

I have added loops in each case. Just check this was what you expected

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.